# IdentityServer4.Models.Client as httppost parameter always null in aspnet core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending an httpPost parameter "client" of type IdentityServer4.Models.Client via a C# console application to a C# web api and **client is always null**.

If I send a different object using the same code, the parameter is received just fine.  This seems to be a problem specific to Identity Server 4 and I don't know what's going on.

Server code:

```
[HttpPost]        
public JsonResult Post(IdentityServer4.Models.Client client){   

    return Json(new { result = true });
}
```

Client code:

```
private static async Task Register(string clientName){

        var controllerName = "BasicClient";             
        var basicClientApi = string.Format("http://localhost:5100/api/{0}", controllerName);
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()){

            var clientData = new IdentityServer4.Models.Client();
            var client = new { client = clientData };
            client.client.ClientName = clientName;

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(basicClientApi, content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                var rawResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject o = JObject.Parse(rawResponse);
                Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
After applying [FromBody] and unwrapping the object, I am still getting null for client in the receiving Web API.  One thing caught my eye on the console application debug screen though.. see the image below:

[image]

The actual client variable is null in the console application, yet JsonConvert was able to serialize it into something.  What's that about?

Comment: `client = new { client = clientData };` - Why are you wrapping your model inside an anonymous object? You need to serialize just your `Client` object, without any wrapping.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I totally missed that. The wrapping will be an issue. You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to believe this, but ultimately the reason why IdentityServer.Models.Client was null in the Web Api post parameter was because the class is decorated with [DebuggerDisplay("{ClientId}")] and I did not provide a ClientId in my test application, so it was always showing up as null when in fact it actually WAS THERE THE WHOLE TIME.  I am glad this issue is behind me, but I am very angry about this "feature".

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping your model inside an anonymous object, which will turn its JSON representation into something which has nothing in common with your original `Client` class.

This:

```
var clientData = new IdentityServer4.Models.Client();
var client = new { client = clientData };
client.client.ClientName = clientName;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client);
```

Will result in a JSON similar to the following:

```
{
    "client": { 
        "clientName": "foo",
        "anotherProperty": "bar",
        // other properties omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

But what you really want is just the `Client` object:

```
{ 
    "clientName": "foo",
    "anotherProperty": "bar",
    // other properties omitted for brevity
}
```

Do not wrap your `clientData`, just serialize it directly to follow the model inside your MVC Action Method:

```
var clientData = new IdentityServer4.Models.Client();
clientData.ClientName = clientName;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientData);
```

For everything to be working, you have to tell the model binder explicitly where to expect the data.

Use `[FromBody]` attribute on the model.

> `[FromBody]`: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the request.

```
[HttpPost]        
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]IdentityServer4.Models.Client client) {

    return Json(new { result = true });
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I have applied the above changes, but I am still having the issue.  Client is null.

I will attach some screen shots too.

Comment: I just discovered that I have a package reference version mismatch...<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.1.3" /> and <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.2.0" />

Comment: I have made both projects use version 2.2.0, I ran nuget locals all -clear, and dotnet restore... but when I hit f12 on the type it still shows the old one being referenced on my web api.  Why won't it reference the newer version of IS4?

Comment: I do not believe the nuget version would change **anything** in your scenario. Also, I do not understand your debugging window, how do you get the `json` variable inside your ASP.NET Core Controller?

Comment: that's the watch window in the console app project, not the project with the web api Controller.  At this point I am almost certain it has to do with differing versions of Client.cs across projects because I followed the above advice and I am still having issues.  It looks like the Web API project includes an EF project as a reference, and the EF project uses IdentityServer4.EntityFramework which is, I think, where the old Client.cs resides